# I have tried to implement linked list for storing student details in the nodes

Tags: c, string, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

this is my code to implement linked list for storing student details in the nodes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Student_Database{
    char Name[100];
    char RegId[100];
    int age;
    double cgpa;
    struct Student_Database*next;
};

void  PushFirst(struct Student_Database* a){
    
    printf("enter the name:");
    fgets(a->Name,sizeof(a->Name),stdin);
    printf("enter the regId");
    fgets(a->RegId,sizeof(a->RegId),stdin);
    printf("enter the age");
    scanf("%d",&a->age);
    printf("enter the cgpa");
    scanf("%lf",&a->cgpa);
    a->next=NULL;
}

void Push(struct Student_Database* a ,struct Student_Database* b){
 
    printf("enter the name:");
    fgets(a->Name,sizeof(a->Name),stdin);
    printf("enter the regId");
    fgets(a->RegId,sizeof(a->RegId),stdin);
    printf("enter the age");
    scanf("%d",&a->age);
    printf("enter the cgpa");
    scanf("%lf",&a->cgpa);
    a->next=NULL;
    b->next=a;
}

void Display(struct Student_Database* a){
    struct Student_Database* ptr=a;
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        printf("name of the student:");
        puts(ptr->Name);
        printf("the regdid:");
        puts(ptr->RegId);
        printf("the age:");
        printf("%d",ptr->age);
        printf("the cgpa:");
        printf("%lf",ptr->cgpa);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}
/*here a is the popped node and b is the node before a   */
void pop(struct Student_Database* a,struct Student_Database* b){
    b->next=NULL;
    
}

int main(){
    struct Student_Database*head;
    struct Student_Database*one;
    
    head=(struct Student_Database*)calloc(1,sizeof(struct Student_Database));
    one=(struct Student_Database*)calloc(1,sizeof(struct Student_Database));
    PushFirst(head);
    Push(one,head);
    Display(head);
   
   }
```

I have Push function such that it takes input of the last node and the node before that.
When i have tried Push(one) it doesn't take input for the name. It takes the input for name for the first node PushFirst(head)

Output:
[image: the output of the code]

Comment: It's a common problem when you mix `fgets` and `scanf`. The `scanf` function will leave the newline in the input buffer, for the next `fgets` call to read as an empty line.

Comment: i tried replacing all the `fgets` with `scanf("%s")` but its not working either @Some progrrammer dude

Comment: And that's because the `%s` format reads *space delimited* words.

Answer (score 0):

because your `fgets` function read the newline character ('\n) in your push function.
with this kind of reading data from console input, you should use `scanf`

```
printf("enter the name: ");
scanf("%s", &a->Name);
printf("enter the regId: ");
scanf("%s", &a->RegId);
printf("enter the age: ");
scanf("%d", &a->age);
printf("enter the cgpa: ");
scanf("%lf", &a->cgpa);
a->next = NULL;
```